# Is it Possible To Limit Permissions for a Time Period?

Tags: 2013

Is there a way to limit users access to a SP2013 page for 5 days, then auto delete their permissions?  This will be used for SharePoints OTB survey and I would like the users access to be removed after about 5 days.  Thanks.

Comment: if you do not find any suggestion by anyone, then my suggestion is to use **Timer Job**

Answer (score 1):

Some PowerShell script and a scheduled task would probably do. It is quite easy to add or remove users. E.g. using powershell to add a user to a group: http://manasbhardwaj.net/add-users-sharepoint-group-using-powershell/

You might need to create a log on how long a user has been a group member to know who to remove.

-SUGGESTION 2
One thing that you might look into is setting Item Level permissions with SharePoint Designer Workflows. The 2010 type would allow you to do so, and the 2013 type workflow would allow waiting periods (certain time or date). There are options to fire a 2010 workflow from a 2013 workflow. See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2012/08/18/how-to-trigger-a-sharepoint-2010-workflow-from-a-sharepoint-2013-workflow.aspx

The one thing you have to figure out, is if you could solve your case with Item level permissions. You cannot set the list or site permissions with a workflow.

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping for something simple as I don't know PowerShell.

Comment: I've added an extra suggestion to try this without programming. Maybe this would help.